# Аналог exit(0);

Tags: java

В c++ я использовал функцию exit(0); для выхода из программы. Есть ли её аналог на java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.exit(0)
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Answer (score 1):

`System.exit(0)` или `return` в основном потоке.